# if $ a_i$ does not divide $ \prod\limits_{i\ne j}{a_j}$ for all $ i$,prove that $ k\leq\pi(n).$

Tags: number-theory

Let $ a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ be positive integers not exceeding
$ n$ such that $ a_i$ does not divide $ \prod\limits_{i\ne j}{a_j}$
for all $ i$. Denote by $ \pi(n)$ is the number of primes not exceeding $ n$.
Prove that $ k\leq\pi(n).$

My attemp:

Let $ \pi(n)=r$ and The primes not exceeding $ n$ be $ \{p_1,p_2,...,p_r\}$.
For each $ a_i$ let the exponent of $ p_j$ in its prime factorization be $ x_{ij}$. And let $ X$ be the corresponding $ k\times r$ matrix with entries $ x_{i,j}$
We are given that for each $ i$, $ \exists j=j(i)$ so that $ x_{ij}>\sum_{m=1}^kx_{mj}$.

Then I can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, let $\pi(n) = r$ and let $\{p_1, \cdots, p_r\}$ denote the primes not exceeding $n$. For any prime $p$ and integer $k$, let $v_p (k)$ denote the largest power of $p$ dividing $k$. Then, we get a matrix of values $$\{v_{p_i} (a_j)\}_{1\le i \le r, 1\le j \le k}$$ and the condition implies that for each $1\le j \le k$, there exists some $1\le g(j) \le r$ such that $v_{p_{g(j)}} (a_j) > \sum_{m \neq j} v_{p_{g(j)}} (a_m)$. In particular, $v_{p_{g(j)}} (a_j) > v_{p_{g(j)}} (a_m)$ for all $m\neq j$.

If $k > \pi(n)$, then by the Pigeonhole Principle, there must be distinct indices $j_1$ and $j_2$ such that $g(j_1) = g(j_2)=:i$. But then both $v_{p_i} (a_{j_1}) > v_{p_i} (a_{j_2})$ and $v_{p_i} (a_{j_1}) < v_{p_i} (a_{j_2})$, contradiction.

We conclude $k \le \pi(n)$.

Comment: I can't understand why exist $j_{1},j_{2}$ such $g(j_{1})=g(j_{2})$,can you explain detail? Thanks

Comment: We have $k$ integers $g(1)$, $g(2)$, $\cdots$, $g(k)$ each of which is between $1$ and $r$ inclusive. If $k>r$, then two of them must be equal -- because if all the $g(i)$ were different, then there would have to be at least $k$ distinct integers between $1$ and $r$.